# Can I use someone else's music/midi?

Tags: legal, music

The music in question is not exactly owned by the other individual either, as it's simply an arrangement of a game's soundtrack as a midi or music sheet.

Am I allowed to use these in my videogame? Should those persons be given credit or should it go to the original composers of the track in the original video game?

Should I ask for permission for the authors of the rearrange? What if the file and site list no author? What if it lists an author but I have no means to reach and ask?

Answer (score 0):

In short: Don't use it.

An arrangement or performance of a song is a derivative work, and as such the composers are owners of the Copyright, even if they didn't do the actual performance or re-arrangement. You always need permission from the rights owner. If you can't determine who that is, you can't get permission, and are thus illegally using it. (With exceptions for music that's old enough that Copyright has expired, fair use exceptions in some countries for short excerpts or scholarly purposes don't apply here)

Disclaimer: I'm not a lawyer, this is not legal advice. You should really see a lawyer about this.